# change cell value on button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table with the following.

```
 Table parts_stock
*--------------------*
| id |  sku  | stock |
|  1 |  101  |   2   |
|  2 |  102  |   3   |
*--------------------*
```

This is my code so far, i'm sure there are many ways to achieve this but ideally I want the qty *value* to change based on which button is clicked on without the page being refreshed (AJAX probably).

```
<tbody>
    <?php

    $query = 'SELECT stock_id, sku, in_stock ';
    $query .= 'FROM parts_stock';
        confirmQuery($query);
    $select_skus = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($select_skus);
    if($num>0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_skus)) {
    $id   = $row['stock_id'];    
    $sku  = $row['sku'];
    $qty  = $row['in_stock'];


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$sku."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$qty."</td>";
    echo "<td>
        <a href='' onclick='rem_qty()' id='minus' name='minus' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>
        <a href='' onclick='add_qty()' id='plus' name='plus' class='btn btn-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>
      </td>"; 
      </td>";    
    }
    }?>
</tbody>
```

ajax_search.js

```
<script>
function rem_qty(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_qty.php",
        data: {id_m: stock_id}
    });
}

function add_qty(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_qty.php",
        data: 'id_p: stock_id'
    });
}

</script>
```

update_qty.php file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id_m'])) {
$r = $_POST['id_m'];
echo $r;
$cur_inv = "SELECT in_stock FROM parts_stock WHERE stock_id = '".$r."'";
$cur_query = mysqli_query($connection, $cur_inv);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cur_query)) {
    $rem_stock = $row['in_stock'];
    $rem_stock -= 1;
}
$inv_update = "UPDATE parts_stock SET in_stock = '".$rem_stock."' WHERE stock_id = '".$value."'";
$inv_query = mysqli_query($connection, $inv_update);
}
if (isset($_POST['id_p'])) {
$a = $_POST['id_p'];
echo $a;
$cur_inv = "SELECT in_stock FROM parts_stock WHERE stock_id = '".$a."'";
$cur_query = mysqli_query($connection, $cur_inv);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cur_query)) {
    $add_stock = $row['in_stock'];
    $add_stock -= 1;
}
$inv_update = "UPDATE parts_stock SET in_stock = '".$add_stock."' WHERE stock_id = '".$value."'";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to use AJAX, you need a separate PHP-File, which handles the AJAXMLHTTPRequest (which esentially is AJAX), but I guess you know that

Comment: yes. I have an ajax file that is working for other tables. I'm just now sure how to setup the function, since that file is setup as a search. I'll paste my AJAX file here. Maybe that will help out

Comment: After click button which value you want to change and how much?

Comment: So you need to Implement the JS to send the request and handle the response?

Comment: each button (+ / - ) will change the value by 1

Comment: You need your JavaScript AJAX code that sends data to a separate PHP page, which usually `echo json_encode($assocArray)`s data back to the same JavaScript, usually in a success function of sorts. In the near future, you'll learn that you should just handle data with PHP, without using it for HTML, with the exception of initial page builds.

Comment: updated my code with what I have so far. No error displays or code functioning properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A simple and complete solution: just change **mysqli_connect** config in both page

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname"); //change dbname 

    $query = 'SELECT id, sku, stock FROM parts_stock';
    //confirmQuery($query);
    $select_skus = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($select_skus);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Sku</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <?php if($num>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_skus)) {
            $id   = $row['id'];    
            $sku  = $row['sku'];
            $qty  = $row['stock'];

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$sku."</td>";
            echo "<td class='stock-{$id}'>".$qty."</td>";
            echo "<td>
                <a class='btn btn-warning' onclick='add_qty({$id})' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'>Value Add</span></a>
                <a class='btn btn-success' onclick='rem_qty({$id})' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'>Value Deduct</span></a>
              </td>";
            echo "</tr>" ;
        }
    }?>
</table>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_qty(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'update_qty.php', //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: {id:id, type:'add'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.success){
                    //successfully added
                    $(".stock-"+id).html(data.data.stock);
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function rem_qty(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'update_qty.php', //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: {id:id, type:'rem'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.success){
                    //successfully added
                    $(".stock-"+id).html(data.data.stock);
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**update_qty.php**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname"); ////change dbname 

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $success = false;  $msg ="";
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $cur_inv = "SELECT * FROM parts_stock WHERE id ={$id}";
        $cur_query = mysqli_query($connection, $cur_inv);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($cur_query)>0){ //if id is exist in database
            if($_POST['type']=="add"){
                $inv_update = "UPDATE parts_stock SET stock = (stock+1) WHERE id = {$id}"; //increase your stock dynamically
            }elseif($_POST['type']=="rem"){
                $inv_update = "UPDATE parts_stock SET stock = (stock-1) WHERE id = {$id}"; //increase your stock dynamically
            }

            $inv_query = mysqli_query($connection, $inv_update);
            if($inv_query){ //If sucess
                $msg = "Successfully Updated"; 
                $success = true;
            }else{ //if failed
                $msg = "Failed to Update";
            }
        }else{
            $msg="Id is not found.";
        }

        $last_inv = "SELECT * FROM parts_stock WHERE id ={$id}";
        $last_query = mysqli_query($connection, $last_inv);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_query);
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>$success, 'msg'=>$msg, 'data'=>$row));
    }
?>
```

> No need extra js file just index.php and update_qty.php

Comment: Thanks for your input. I however cancelled this project as this was causing other errors on my entire application. Im going to mark this as answered since i ran this on a different server and it did function properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `HTML Button` to have a `onClick` event like this `onclick="buttonSubtract1('<?php if(isset($val['itm_code'])){echo $val['itm_code'];}?>')"`**(You can fetch the itm_code from your db)**.Then Write your `AJAX` for `Request` and `Response`. And You need to Pass the `itm_code` through `var x`. e.g for like this `xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/get_items.php?val=" +x, true);`

In AJAX file

```
$item_cat = $_SESSION['item_cat']; // get a category from session
    $iname=$_GET['val']; //get the value from main php file
    if(!key_exists($item_cat)
    {
       $_SESSION['main'][$iname] = "1";
    }
    else
    {
       $_SESSION['main'][$item_cat][$iname]++;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION['main']);
    echo "</pre>";
```

**EDIT 1**

```
function buttonSubtract1(x)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.location.assign('items.php');
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/get_items.php?val=" +x, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: this is in the js file or the php file?

Comment: php file only . there are two files something.php and ajax_somthing.php. i worked alredy same concept for ordering purpose.its worked

Comment: I'll have to modify this to suite me needs as you are using sessions. I'll get back with you on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Working example

demo.php

<?php

$query = 'SELECT id, sku, stock ';
$query .= 'FROM parts_stock';
    confirmQuery($query);
$select_skus = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($select_skus);
if($num>0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_skus)) {
$id   = $row['id'];    
$sku  = $row['sku'];
$qty  = $row['stock'];

 $data = "";

 $data .= "<tr>";
 $data .= "<td>{$sku}</td>";
 $data .= "<td>{$qty}</td>";
 $data .= "<td>
    <a class='btn btn-warning' href='inventory.php?source=edit_inventory&id={$id}'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>
    <a class='btn btn-success' href='inventory.php?source=edit_inventory&id={$id}'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>
  </td>"; 
echo $a;
  exit;    
}
}?>


  AJAX:


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
         <table >
         <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Sku</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
         </tr>
         <tbody id="mytable">
          </tbody>
         </table>

        <button id="clickme">Click</button>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#clickme").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
      url:"demo.php",
      type:"GET",
      beforeSend:function() {
   $("#mytable").empty();
},
success:function(response){
      $("#mytable").append(response);
}, error:function(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

 })
}); 
  });
```

Comment: This will not work for me as you are sourcing an old version of jquery. There is some conflicts and some depreciated code.